# Export type into python

Tags: c++, python, boost, types, export

I want to export singleton into python using boost.python and use it there. Here is the code:

```
class ConfigManager : public boost::serialization::singleton<ConfigManager> {};
inline ConfigManager &configManager() { return ConfigManager::get_mutable_instance(); }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ConfigManager)
{
    bp::class_<ConfigManager, boost::noncopyable>("ConfigManager", bp::no_init);
    bp::def("getHandle", &configManager, bp::return_value_policy<bp::copy_non_const_reference>());
}
```

Now, when I call `getHandle` in python, I get:

> TypeError: No to_python (by-value)
>   converter found for C++ type:
>   ConfigManager

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copy_non_const_reference` will try to copy your reference to a Python object, you should use instead `bp::reference_existing_object`, I tried here and the error message disappeared